# unordered_set - very small max_bucket_count

Tags: c++11, unordered-set

Update: I see this "problem" on Windows using Visual Studio 2013.  I do not see this with the same code on Linux using Clang 3.3 and a very recent version of the llvm standard library.  Still, I am not ready to just write this off as Microsoft bug.

I noticed a curious issue with the an unordered_set I am working with.  I have a load_factor of 1 and maximum size in the millions, yet the following shows that the maximum_bucket_count is just 8.  I tried this with sets of different types.

Can anyone explain this?

This is supposed to be an system or library implementation limit, not an initialization or configuration dependent number. I have seen examples of the code below where the max_bucket_count is the same is the max_count (i.e., millions)

```
std::unordered_set<int> testSet;
std::cout << "max_size = " << testSet.max_size() << std::endl;
std::cout << "max_bucket_count = " << testSet.max_bucket_count() << std::endl;
std::cout << "max_load_factor = " << testSet.max_load_factor() << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/bucket_size

`bucket_size(bucket index)` is the number of elements in the bucket with that index. It is supposed to be small.

`bucket_count()` is the number of buckets. It's supposed to be approximately `size()`.

This is what happens on my computer (after inserting 1000000 random integers):

```
size = 999891
bucket_count = 1056323
maximum bucket_size = 9
max_size = 1152921504606846975
max_bucket_count = 1152921504606846975
max_load_factor = 1
```

After 20000000 random integers:

```
size = 19953913
bucket_count = 36473443
maximum bucket_size = 9
```

It can be seen that the bucket count is actually more than the size but still the buckets are small.

Comment: The original question is about max_bucket_count.  The title was correct but I had to fix a typo in the the question body.  Note that your output the max_bucket_count is way above TRILLIONS versus just 8 on my system. From cpprefernce.com: max_bucket_count(): Returns the maximum number of buckets the container is able to hold due to system or library implementation limitations.

Comment: What is the standard library implementation you are using?

Comment: Good question - I will update the question.  I see this "problem" on Windows using Visual Studio 2013.  I do not see this with the same code on Linux using Clang 3.3 and a very recent version of the llvm standard library.

Comment: The `max_size` and `max_bucket_count` values look to me suspiciously like the kinds of numbers you see when you misinterpret a float/double as an integer or something. Definitely suspicious - maybe some functions somewhere in the implementation that are prototyped wrong or something...